# Не работает datepicker

Tags: bootstrap, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, mvc

Моя вьюшка:

```
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-3.1.1.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-ui-1.12.1.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-ui-1.12.1.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $('.date-picker').datepicker();
    })
</script>

@Html.EditorFor(model => model.EndDate, new { @class = "form-control date-picker" })
```

Comment: Добавьте *@Html.EditorFor* перед скриптом

Comment: @VadimProkopchuk не помогло

Comment: Adrian, добавили между первыми 3 и последним? И нету необходимости подключать 2 раза одну и ту же библиотеку, можно удалить `~/Scripts/jquery-ui-1.12.1.js`